# How to use NestJS dtos in a frontend react app?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-decorator

In my typescript/react application, I would like to be able to reuse DTOs that I have declared inside of NestJS in order to have them declared in one place.

Right now, I have created an npm package that is used as a dependency in both application, which is fine until I have to apply some decorators for properties in the DTO, which is something I can have without adding decorator support in my types npm package.

- Is this not a good practice and should I keep frontend and backend dtos separate?
- If it is a good practice: a) Should I add decorator support in my types package and just do it there? b) Is there a more elegant way to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: I'm in a similar position. If you were to go back in time, what advice would you give yourself? Would you recommend reusing the dto's/class validator in the frontend or was it too much of a hassle?

I feel like I've already written the validation logic and I'm wondering if it is worth going down the rabit hole of trying to export the classes from nestjs somehow so I can reuse them in a frontend sveltekit app.